# What happened to Martin Septim after the Avatar of Akatosh became stone? (Spoilers)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

At the end of the main questline for Oblivion, Martin Septim

> breaks the Amulet of the Kings to summon Akatosh, in which Akatosh put an end to the Crisis.

However, Martin disappeared, and both the game itself and all sources I read through are vague on his fate. What happened to him? I figured he simply died, but I am unsure.

Comment: Does a 10+ year old game really need a spoiler warning?

Comment: It could... though unlikely, it may be new to someone.

Comment: I didn't play it till a few months ago!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's implied that the Avatar of Akatosh is Martin

> Once the final cutscene is over, Ocato will run up to you and ask about Martin: *"What happened? Where's Martin? I must congratulate him! Mehrunes Dagon is defeated! Cast back into Oblivion! We've won!"* When you tell him Martin is gone, he says: *"What do you mean, gone? We saw the Temple dome explode, **the avatar of Akatosh appear... that was Martin?**"*

Source: [The Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages > Oblivion:Brother Martin > Quest-Related Events > Aftermath](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Brother_Martin#Aftermath)

the reason Martin was able to became Akatosh's Avatar is because his bloodline descends from Saint Alessia

> The Dragon God imbued Alessia's line with blood from his own heart, initiating a sacred compact which kept the Dragonfires lit and Oblivion's influence barred from Mundus, so long as those of the Dragon Blood wore the Amulet of Kings. Ever since, the legitimate rulers of the Empire have been called Dragonborn: Alessia's successors, Reman Cyrodiil and his heirs, and finally the Septim Dynasty. Indeed, the title is particularly associated with Tiber Septim himself, perhaps because he made notable use of the thu'um in his early conquests. Only these true rulers, approved by Akatosh, could wear the Amulet of Kings and light the Dragonfires.

Source: [The Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages > Lore:Dragonborn > Dragonborn Emperors](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Dragonborn)

one of the qualifications for a Septim Emperor is that they use the Amulet of Kings to relight the Dragonfires. to do this the Emperor-to-be (Martin) has to have Akatosh's blood in them.

given that people say Martin died we can assume the giant Akatosh Statue that's coming out of the Temple of the One has no life in it so Martin is dead

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So Martin (or at least what is left of him) is the Akatash statue?

Comment: @TheMattbat999 i assume so, the statue is exactly where the Avatar stood and as i said it's implied that Martin became the Avatar

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I will accept this answer later if no one else answers!